# Using clicked variable within Ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to reference a dynamic variable used in the CSS class within an Ajax call.

I have tried the following to no avail.

```
function watchlist($video_id, $user_id){
    $.ajax({
        url: "watchlist.php",
        data: {video_id : $video_id, user_id: $user_id},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            $(".watchlist-$video_id").html("<i class='fa fa-minus-square' aria-hidden='true'></i>");
        }
    });
}
```

How do I use the video_id : $video_id in data within the success function.

I hope that question makes sense.

Thanks,

John

Comment: String concatenation or template literals...

Comment: `$(".watchlist-"+$video_id)` works!

Comment: @Roy Perfect! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".watchlist-" + $video_id)` will work!